# Auto login on first request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For testing and convenience purposes I would like my application to be able to automatically login a user (which I will specify in the web.config appSettings) on the first web request when I start my application.

I tried doing this from the Application_BeginRequest method using a static bool flag to see if it was the first request (and yes, I realize that between running my application if it doesn't recompile or otherwise reset the app pool that it will remember this value and that's fine).

However it's not quite working right... getting some mixed results that are hard to explain in a short message. What would be a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: This needs a lot more details. You should probably use one of the built in Authentication methods.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich Yeah, I am using a semi-custom rolled authentication deal and in my regular sign in page the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie() method wasn't working as expected. So I had to use FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket) and then add the cookie directly to the response. Haven't figured out why it works that way but not the other, but didn't really want to get into details about that stuff. Really just looking for suggestions from a higher level... i.e. like maybe suggestions on another way to do this that doesn't involve Application_BeginRequest.

Comment: You should probably use the Application_AuthenticateRequest instead of the BeginRequest, but I doubt it would make much difference. Perhaps you should be specific around what's actually failing. Using this model is by far the most common way to handle authentication.

Comment: Thanks. I actually figured out what my problem was... long story short I ended up writing code to see if an auth ticket was set because IsAuthenticated doesn't become true until the 'next' request. I had tried redirecting, but that caused other issues for me as the current request doesn't stop processing when you do response.redirect().